# Cannot add Facebook App as a page tab

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've got a problem with creating an App that could be then added to facebook pages as a tab. The problem is probably because I'm new to this facebook stuff and I'm doing something wrong here.

Currently I'm trying to use both URL and JS api call (as I'm using language other than english - the errors I put below could differ a bit from what they are in english). Of course APP_ID below is replaced with the proper app id.

URL:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=facebook.com

which results in 'There was an error. Try again later.'

JS:
`FB.ui({
  method: 'pagetab',
  app_id: APP_ID
}, function(response){});`

which results in: 'This application could not be activated on your profile.'

The profile i"m trying to add this of course has some facebook Pages on it. The app I'm trying to add was created accordingly to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ . I've created a simple Page Tab app, entered a test name and URL, and that's it. When I;m in the fb dev dashboard there's a green icon next to the app that says 'live and available to all users'.

Does anyone have idea what could be wrong here, and why can't I add this app to my FB page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There cause of the error is likely to be two reasons:

1. The `redirect_uri` is incorrect. It must be part of your app domain (as setup in the App Settings). If you app is hosted at `http://myapp.com`, then the redirect_url needs to be on the same domain, e.g. `http:/myapp.com/installed.php`.
2. You have not setup the Application correctly on the App Settings page. Have you added the correct "Page Tab" settings? At the minimum, the `Page Tab Name`, `Page Tab URL` and `Secure Page Tab URL` are required.

Comment: It must have been a typo, because I'm pretty sure I was doing everything OK :) Nevertheless, your answer made me try again while being more careful, and I'm all good now. Thx!